# Populating a SQLite3 database from a .txt file with Python

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to setup a website in django which allows the user to send queries to a database containing information about their representatives in the European Parliament. I have the data in a comma seperated .txt file with the following format:

> Parliament, Name, Country, Party_Group, National_Party,  Position
>
> 7, Marta Andreasen, United Kingdom, Europe of freedom and democracy Group, United Kingdom Independence Party, Member
>
> etc....

I want to populate a SQLite3 database with this data, but so far all the tutorials I have found only show how to do this by hand. Since I have 736 observations in the file I dont really want to do this.

I suspect this is a simple matter, but I would be very grateful if someone could show me how to do this.

Thomas

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So assuming your `models.py` looks something like this:

```
class Representative(models.Model):
    parliament = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    party_group = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    national_party = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

You can then run `python manage.py shell` and execute the following:

```
import csv
from your_app.models import Representative
# If you're using different field names, change this list accordingly.
# The order must also match the column order in the CSV file.
fields = ['parliament', 'name', 'country', 'party_group', 'national_party', 'position']
for row in csv.reader(open('your_file.csv')):
    Representative.objects.create(**dict(zip(fields, row)))
```

And you're done.

**Addendum (edit)**

Per Thomas's request, here's an explanation of what `**dict(zip(fields,row))` does:

So initially, `fields` contains a list of field names that we defined, and `row` contains a list of values that represents the current row in the CSV file.

```
fields = ['parliament', 'name', 'country', ...]
row = ['7', 'Marta Andreasen', 'United Kingdom', ...]
```

What `zip()` does is it combines two lists into one list of pairs of items from both lists (like a zipper); i.e. `zip(['a','b,'c'], ['A','B','C'])` will return `[('a','A'), ('b','B'), ('c','C')]`. So in our case:

```
>>> zip(fields, row)
[('parliament', '7'), ('name', 'Marta Andreasen'), ('country', 'United Kingdom'), ...]
```

The `dict()` function simply converts the list of pairs into a dictionary.

```
>>> dict(zip(fields, row))
{'parliament': '7', 'name': 'Marta Andreasen', 'country': 'United Kingdom', ...}
```

The `**` is a way of converting a dictionary into a keyword argument list for a function. So `function(**{'key': 'value'})` is the equivalent of `function(key='value')`. So in out example, calling `create(**dict(zip(field, row)))` is the equivalent of:

```
create(parliament='7', name='Marta Andreasen', country='United Kingdom', ...)
```

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: If you're loading this into Django, definitely look into Aram's solution here for use. It's taking advantage of the django ORM bits for you, so you don't need to mess with the schema directly. Not a big deal if you're comfortable with SQL schema, but I found it made things much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aram. I am still learning python, so could you you explain what the (**dict(zip(...)) part of the last line does?

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aram, this really helps! I am continually suprised at how frindly the stack overflow community is the newcomers :)

P.S: the code worked perfectly :)

Comment: @AramDulyan What's the best way to do this from within a python script? By using subprocess.call?

Comment: @jonnyd42 How do you mean? My answer only has Python code, you can just put it in your Python script.

Answer (score 4):

As SiggyF says and only slightly differently than Joschua:

Create a text file with your schema, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE politicians (
    Parliament text, 
    Name text, 
    Country text, 
    Party_Group text, 
    National_Party text, 
    Position text
);
```

Create table:

```
>>> import csv, sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('my.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> with open('myschema.sql') as f:            # read in schema file 
...   schema = f.read()
... 
>>> c.execute(schema)                          # create table per schema 
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1392f50>
>>> conn.commit()                              # commit table creation
```

Use csv module to read file with data to be inserted:

```
>>> csv_reader = csv.reader(open('myfile.txt'), skipinitialspace=True)
>>> csv_reader.next()                          # skip the first line in the file
['Parliament', 'Name', 'Country', ...

# put all data in a tuple
# edit: decoding from utf-8 file to unicode
>>> to_db = tuple([i.decode('utf-8') for i in line] for line in csv_reader)
>>> to_db                                      # this will be inserted into table
[(u'7', u'Marta Andreasen', u'United Kingdom', ...
```

Insert data:

```
>>> c.executemany("INSERT INTO politicians VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);", to_db)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1392f50>
>>> conn.commit()
```

Verify that all went as expected:

```
>>> c.execute('SELECT * FROM politicians').fetchall()
[(u'7', u'Marta Andreasen', u'United Kingdom', ...
```

**Edit**:
And since you've decoded (to unicode) on input, you need to be sure to encode on output.
For example:

```
with open('encoded_output.txt', 'w') as f:
  for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM politicians').fetchall():
    for col in row:
      f.write(col.encode('utf-8'))
      f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the elaborate answer! Every step works, except when i try:

c.executemany("INSERT INTO politicians VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);", to_db)

Then i get the following error:

ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

I have saved the text file with a utf8 encoding, so I have no idea what is happening here...

Comment: @Thomas: You're welcome. I updated the example to handle decoding from utf-8, and also showed how to encode back to utf-8 on output. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks Adam, for a beginner this whole encoding business can be quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the data using the csv module. Then you can create an insert sql statement and use the method [executemany](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany):

```
  cursor.executemany(sql, rows)
```

or use [add_all](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/sessions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all) if you use sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2):

You asked what the create(**dict(zip(fields, row))) line did.

I don't know how to reply directly to your comment, so I'll try to answer it here.

zip takes multiple lists as args and returns a list of their correspond elements as tuples.

zip(list1, list2) => [(list1[0], list2[0]), (list1[1], list2[1]), .... ]

dict takes a list of 2-element tuples and returns a dictionary mapping each tuple's first element (key) to its second element (value).

create is a function that takes keyword arguments. You can use **some_dictionary to pass that dictionary into a function as keyword arguments.

create(**{'name':'john', 'age':5}) => create(name='john', age=5)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work: (not tested)

```
# Open database (will be created if not exists)
conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/your_file.db')

c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''create table representatives
(parliament text, name text, country text, party_group text, national_party text, position text)''')

f = open("thefile.txt")
for i in f.readlines():
    # Insert a row of data
    c.execute("""insert into representatives
                 values (?,?,?,?,?,?)""", *i.split(", ")) # *i.split(", ") does unpack the list as arguments

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the cursor if we are done with it
c.close()
```

Comment: Hi Joschua, thanks for the reply! However I keep getting this error when using your example above:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomasjensen/Documents/sql_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    c.execute("""insert into MEP (Parliament, Name, Country, Party_Group, Home_Party, Position) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", *i.split(","))
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (162 given)

Comment: Simply remove the leading asterisk from `*i.split(", ")`. However, the fact that the error message says "162 [arguments] given" suggests that there will be more issues to follow. I would also strongly recommend using any of the other answers currently on this page, which all use the "csv" library, rather than relying on `split(", ")`, which will cause you a lot of grief.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a simple method using sqlite3, you can do it using these 3 steps:

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite3
sqlite> .separator ","
sqlite> .import myfile.txt table_name
```

However do keep the following points in mind:

1. The `.txt` file should be in the **same directory** as your `db.sqlite3`,
   otherwise use an absolute path `"/path/myfile.txt"` when importing
2. Your schema for tables (number of columns) should match with the number of values seperated by commas in **each row** in the txt file

You can use the `.tables` command to [verify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209464/8407719) your table name

```
SQLite version 3.23.1 2018-04-10 17:39:29
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
auth_group                  table_name               
auth_group_permissions      django_admin_log          
auth_permission             django_content_type       
auth_user                   django_migrations         
auth_user_groups            django_session            
auth_user_user_permissions
```