# how to see the table in my database after creating and migrating models in django

Tags: django, django-models, visual-studio-code, database-connection, mysql-cluster

i tried connecting to my sql cloud cluster in visual studio code
Code for settings.py is-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME':'aras',
        'USER':'arasuser',
        'PASSWORD':'**********',
        'HOST':'mysql-numbers-0.cloudclusters.net',
        'connection':'connect1',
    }
}
```

Later, i created a model and run migrations . but yet i am unable to see the table in my database.
am i connecting it right ?

**UPDATED**
models.py code

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

Comment: please add models.py code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install and login in `DB Browser for SQLite`: https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Go through this link.

[python sqlite use in terminal -django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209209/python-sqlite-use-in-terminal-django)

---

[image]

models.py

```
 from django.db import models
 
 class Event(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length=120)
     event_date = models.DateTimeField('Event Date')
     venue = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     manager = models.CharField(max_length=60)
     description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

after creating models

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Terminal output:

```
Migrations for 'events':
  events\migrations\0001_initial.py
  - Create model Event
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Terminal output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: events
Running migrations:
  Applying events.0001_initial... OK
```

Django uses the model to generate SQL,Try this command

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate events 0001_initial

BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Event
--
CREATE TABLE "events_event" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    "name" varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    "event_date" datetime NOT NULL, 
    "venue" varchar(120) NOT NULL, 
    "manager" varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    "description" text NOT NULL
);
COMMIT;
```

database:

[image]

python manage.py sqlmigrate events 0001_initial

More info : https://djangobook.com/mdj2-models/#creating-database-records

Comment: updated in question - models.py but i dont want to use sqllite i want to use my online database server.

Comment: please login with your credientials then create a database with named in settings.py

Comment: Then add models ,make migrations and finally migrate.